# pipeline symbol pattern matching in jmeter

Tags: pattern-matching, jmeter, jmenu

Getting "UTR\|UTIBH0000000000\|"; in response in JMeter.
Want to read \|UTIBH000000000\ from "UTR\|UTIBH0000000000\|";
I am able to read using `(.+?)` but the **error** comes:
    **Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 3, column 88.  Encountered: "|" (124), after : "\"UTR\"**

Tried:

1. "UTR(.)";
2. "UTR[.]";
3. "UTR.";
4. "UTR(.+?)";

but no success.

Also tried tried similar question but no success.

**Script:**

```
${__log(${__eval("SUCC01"+"UserID:"+"${__P(FinacleUserID)}"+": Payment Order ID - "+"${SuccessPaymentID}"+"UTR No:-"+"${UTRNO}"+" Verified Successfully")},,,)}
```

**Applying Regular Expression Extractor on:** window.returnValue = "UTR\|UTIBH0000000000\|";

**Regular Expression:** `window.returnValue = "UTR(.+?)"`

Comment: Please show the code that gets the error. There's no `|` in the regex `(.+?)`.

Comment: Script: ${__log(${__eval("SUCC01"+"UserID:"+"${__P(FinacleUserID)}"+":    Payment Order ID - "+"${SuccessPaymentID}"+"UTR No:-"+"${UTRNO}"+" Verified Successfully")},,,)}

Applying Regular Expression Extractor on: window.returnValue = "UTR\|UTIBH0000000000\|";

Comment: Please edit that into your question, it's unreadable in comments.

Comment: May be this is the error is related to Token parsing , because the regular expression that i am using is able to extract the value. And after writing the value it shows error: Parsing Error: Lexical error at line ....

Comment: I don't see any regular expression use in the script you posted.

Comment: Uhm, are you sure "There's no | in the regex".  I wonder why this pattern matches both "delete" and "insert":  Pattern.compile("^(?i)(INSERT|DELETE\\s(.+?)\\s")

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

UTR(\\[^\\]*\\)

[image]